# How to get row id on modal button on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a button in a row of data in datatables, if the button is clicked, the modal will open and user can update some data, the data is taken using ajax and sent to another php file.
[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlH11.png)
[modal open when the button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClhSp.png)

The problem is, when i clicked the button, the row i get is always 1 (the first row), so the data in the first row will be the one updated instead of the row where the button is clicked. Here is the code for the button.

```
            <td>
          
            <?php 
              if ($row['status'] == 0){
            ?>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit"  name="buttonModal" id="buttonModal" data-row="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
              <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
            </button>
          
            <?php
              }else{
            ?>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit"  name="buttonModal" id="buttonModal" data-row="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"disabled>
              <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
            </button>
            
            <?php
              }
            ?>
          </td>
```

The modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="modalEdit">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <!-- Modal Header -->
              <div class="modal-header text-light" style="background-color: #FF9B6A">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Status Pembayaran Peserta</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <!-- Modal body -->
              <div class="modal-body">
              <tr>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <form method="POST">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status" id="approved" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="approved"> Approved </label>
                      <br>
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status" id="rejected" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="rejected"> Rejected </label>
                    </form>
                  </div>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">Catatan untuk peserta: </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                      <textarea class="form-control" id="catatan" placeholder="Catatan"></textarea>
                  </td>
                  <p style="font-size: 14px">Di isi jika ada</p>
              </tr>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
              <p style="color: red">Setelah Anda mengedit, maka sistem secara otomatis akan mengirimkan E-mail mengenai status pembayaran kepada peserta yang bersangkutan.</p>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Save</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="close">Close</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable();
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        // if($('#status').val() != "" && $('#data-row').val() != ""){
        if($('#status').val() != "" ){
            var status = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();

            var element = document.getElementById('buttonModal');
            var row = element.getAttribute('data-row');
            alert(row);

            let fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("status",status);
            fd.append("row",row);
            $.ajax({
                url: "sisiAdmin_action.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    // alert(res);
                    if(res == 'Berhasil update status'){
                        Swal.fire({
                        position: 'top-middle',
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Berhasil update status',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2000
                        })
                        $('#status').val("");
                        $('#data-row').val("");
                    }
                    else{
                        Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        text: 'Gagal update status'
                        })
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Gagal");
                } 
            });
        }
        else{
            Swal.fire('Data belum lengkap!')
        }
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        window.location.reload();
    });
  });
</script>
```

UPDATE: I managed to open the modal through button onclick with this, but still can't get the row number...

```
 $(document).on('click','#buttonModal',function(){
  $("#modalEdit").modal('show');
});
```

UPDATE 2: I got the row by doing this now i have to find out how to get the int value from {"row": int}

```
var id;
$(document).on('click','#buttonModal',function(){
  $("#modalEdit").modal('show');
  id = $(this).data();
  var str = JSON.stringify(id);
  alert(JSON.stringify(id));
});
```

UPDATE 3: Okay, i did it. Here's how i get the row id

```
var id;
var row;
$(document).on('click','#buttonModal',function(){
  $("#modalEdit").modal('show');
  id = $(this).data();
  var str = JSON.stringify(id);
  const obj = JSON.parse(str);
  row = obj.row;
  // alert(row);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you must prevent setting non-unique id to your elements, it's important to have a distinct id attribute name per each element of your DOM, according to [html living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html) :

> The class, id, and slot attributes may be specified on all HTML elements. ……. When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element’s tree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any ASCII whitespace.

after that, when u trigger an event on $("#submit") element then you cannot get previous triggered target to fetch row id from it, so by selecting  `var element = document.getElementById('buttonModal');` u just get the first one.

the solution is to run modal programmatically by JavaScript :

```
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

when click event on row triggered :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonModal").click(function(){
        $("#modalEdit").modal('show');
    });
});
```

now put an hidden input element in edit modal form :

```
 <input type="hidden" name="row_id" id="row_container">
```

and before showing modal set it as well :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonModal").click(function(event){
        $("#row_container").value($(this).data('row'));
        $("#modalEdit").modal('show');
    });
});
```

then send the form .

Comment: i tried it, but the modal won't show

Comment: paste $("#modalEdit").modal('show'); in your console and see if modal shows or not

Comment: did u use jquery and bootstrap ?

Comment: yeah i used bootstrap 5 and also jquery

Comment: the modal shows when i paste it in my console

Comment: i changed the button to:                                                                                          
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="buttonModal" >
                  <i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>

Comment: why !??!  u need its data-attributes .

Comment: ohh okay, i'll put it back

Comment: paste :    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonModal").click(function(){
        $("#modalEdit").modal('show');
    });
});  
into console , see if modal shows after clicking at edit button or not ,

Comment: there's an error, sisiAdmin.php:242 Uncaught ReferenceError: row is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (sisiAdmin.php:242)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.5.1.js:5429)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.5.1.js:5233)

Comment: i pasted this:  $(document).ready(function(){ $("#buttonModal").click(function(){ $("#modalEdit").modal('show'); }); }); , the modal shows

Comment: ok so there must be a problem with loading js scripts and probably you will encounter furthermore posterior bugs, u must debug it and find the problems, I can't help u anymore in the commenting system because those are completely different issues.

Comment: okay, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Using the id attribute in multiple places makes your code invalid.

It looks like you were looking for data after click, I can suggest you use the event parameter in the callback and use that to figure out which button is clicked. For more detail look at https://api.jquery.com/submit/